# Writing code Javascript and other languages

Tags: coding-style

What is the general consenses, in this case i will be using JavaScript as an example:

Which one is more clear and correct A or B.. ? Please explain why, it might help others with their own coding style

A) Assign value to variable then check variable, then return value

```
...
mm = fecha.getMonth().length;
if (mm<=1)
  {
  return '0' + mm;
  }
...
```

B) Check value directly then return value

```
...
if (fecha.getMonth().length<=1)
  {
   return '0'+ fecha.getMonth().length; 
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to condition the value and not using it later

```
if (fecha.getMonth().length<=1){
    ...
}
```

No need to create another variable which name could be used later and would lead to an error

```
let month = fecha.getMonth();
if( month.length<=1 ){
    ...
}
...
let month = document.querySelector('input#month').value; // Error 'month' has already been declared
...
```

If you have to check the value and furthermore use it

```
mm = fecha.getMonth().length;
if (mm<=1)
    return mm;
}
```

Keeps the code clean when there are cases like this

```
aType = document.querySelector('A').children[0].classList[0].split('-')[1]
if(aType != 'relative'){
    return document.querySelectorAll(aType)[1];
}
```

Which otherwise it would look like this

```
if(document.querySelector('A').children[0].classList[0].split('-')[1] != 'relative'){
    return document.querySelectorAll(document.querySelector('A').children[0].classList[0].split('-')[1])[1];
}
```